# CSS "text-decoration: none" does not seem to work

Tags: html, css, text-decorations

There are a lot of questions in StackOverflow similar to this, but I wasn't able to find an answer to this simple question. Why the following code does not work as expected?

```html
<pre style="text-decoration: underline;">
underlined
underlined
<span style="text-decoration: none;">should NOT be underlined</span>
underlined
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: inline-block` to **span**.

```html
<pre style="text-decoration: underline;">
underlined
underlined
<span style="text-decoration: none; display: inline-block">should NOT be underlined</span>
underlined
</pre>
```

Comment: Why do I need it?

Comment: I don't know exactly why, but `text-decoration` property doesn't work on `inline` elements or at least doesn't work as expected. `span` element's default display property is `inline` so changing it to `inline-block` or `block` normally solves it. I have encountered this problem several times and this is how I solved it.

Comment: Setting `display: inline-block;` alone (and removing `text-decoration: none;`) also removes the underline from the `span` element. This adds another mystery to this strange behavior!

Comment: Wow yes it actually does. I'll try to find some explanation about it.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli the duplicate contain the explanation